# Trying to upgrade to rails 3.1 getting the error: method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

we have been using rails 3.0.9 for a long time, because of dependencies we now want to upgrade to the latest version. We set the gem file from:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

To:

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'rake'
gem "actionmailer"
```

And now when we try to run rails, get the following error:

```
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000102b66c48> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/xxx/Sites/picasso/config/environments/development.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /Users/xxx/Sites/picasso/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
```

Ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to only put

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
```

in you Gemfile and run the `bundle` command.
You should not have to worry about actionmailer or rake in your gemfile.

Comment: Except you shouldn't jump over versions when upgrading, so the OP should change it to `gem 'rails', '3.1.4'` first, then after ensuring everything works, change it to `3.2.2`.